# PHPExcel set large text in cell?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Has anyone worked on PHPExcel with long text?

I used setCellValue('C2', $text)

but when I export excel the text hasn't enought.

My code test is below:

https://anotepad.com/notes/sdi7ta

Comment: Not sure why you want to cram all that data into one cell, but Excel can only contain 32,767 characters, you have around 62,200 characters. I suggest splitting up your string into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use `mergecells()` which will merge your data across multiple cells

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:E4');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','The quick brown fox.');`

[image]

[Source](http://consistentcoder.com/merge-cells-in-phpexcel)